# need formula that finds cells that have @ sign and pastes it in new Sheet/column

Tags: excel-formula

In excel on page 1 column A i have all sorts of information-names/emails/states, I need to find cells that have @ sign (emails) and paste emails in new Sheet/column. Can I do this?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Filter for cells that contain @ and then copy/paste the results to a new sheet.

Comment: Ohh my. I feel stupid. Thanks, tigeravatar, for great advise!
I'm not very proficient in Excel as you see.